# Android: how to resume main thread after download is finished

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, resume

What can I do, if I'm in any Activity and I want download a file (using thread) and at same time I want the main thread waits until download is finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).. from activity

```
new DownloadTask(this).execute();
```

The task for example:

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>  {

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;  
private Context context;

/**
 * 
 * @param context
 * @param pdfDoc the document of the PDF
 */
public DownloadTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {  
        progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    //download here
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

}
}
```

Comment: To further add, your main thread should not totally lock up while it waits.  Assume the user will be playing with other elements on the Activity or even terminate it before the download finishes.  Using the sample Async above will allow just that.

Comment: I can't create my activity before the download.

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTask and callbacks.

```
public interface DownloadCallback<T>{
    public void onFinishDownload(T downloadedResult);
}


public static void downloadString(String url, DownloadCallback<String> callback){
    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){

        String result;            

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {  
            // Do things before downloading on UI Thread
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

             //download here
             result = download(url);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void result) {
            // Do things on UI thread after downloading, then execute your callback
            if (callback != null) callback.onFinishDownloading(result);
        }


    }.execute();
}
```

And to use this, you just do this:

```
downloadString("http://www.route.to.your.string.com", new DownloadCallback<String>(){
    public void onFinishDownloading(String downloadedResult){
         Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this, downloadedResult, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: With this approach you can even reuse your callback for other result types in other download tasks ;-)

Comment: This way:
A) Main thread executes onPreExecute, then sleeps.
B) New thread executes doInBackground. Main Thread is not clogged meanwhile, you can do whatever you want.
C) Main thread awakes and executes onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the thread to communicate with he main thread, telling that download is finished, use a [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)
This code will help you understand it

```
MyHnadler handler;
onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
{
 setContent..
...
 handler=new MyHandler();
 new MyThread().start();
}
public class MyHandler extends Handler
{
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what) {
            case 1:   //....threading over
                         //write your code here
                   break;
            case2 : //if you want to be notiifed of something else
                   ..
 }

public class MyThread extends Thread
{
 @Override
 public void run()
 {
   //run the threa
   //and when over
   Message msg=handler.getMessage();
   msg.what=1;
   handler.sendMessage(msg);   //send the message to handler
 }
}
}
```

As you can see the thread **communicates** with the UI thread via the **Handler**. In the above example, I have only sent any object from the thread to the UI thread. To do that just do `msg.obj=your_obj` in the thread. It can be any object. Hope this helps you:)